# Sencha Ext.device.Device HelloWorld Hangs

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

```
I am a newbie on Sencha, and carried out the following steps:
    sencha -sdk ~/SDKs/sencha/touch-2.3.1/ generate app HelloWorld HelloWorld
    cd helloWorld
    sencha cordova init com.example.HelloWorld HelloWorld
    Then update cordova.local.properties with: cordova.platforms=android

Followed by:
    cd cordova
    cordova platform add android
    sencha app build native
    cordova run
```

## Helloworld loads ok on Android Tablet

```
Original app.js was 
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

This was amended to
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'Ext.device.Device'
],

Followed by:
    sencha app build native
    cordova run
```

## Helloworld doesn't loads completely it hangs at blinking dots

I have tried google but can't see the issue, Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cordova 3.0 or higher you need add the [cordova device plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/doc/index.md) to cordova

```
$ cd cordova
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

and the feature to config.xml:

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Worked a treat, Thank you for your time in providing this response.

Comment: Excellent answer. My app also hung as soon as I require 'Ext.device.Device' and installing the plugin fixed it, but I did not need to edit the config.xml, what is the purpose of adding that? I'm trying on iOS 7